# Recovering files of Metamask local storage

Tags: restore, metamask

Metamask crashed on my chrome session, and when I clicked restore, I had to input my seed, and I don’t have it

So I tried to get the seed from the vault on thé local storage.

But the files are now overwritten by the relaunch of metamask when I clicked « restore »

Is there a way to get the old files back ?